# Cannot run Jupyter notebook with Spark kernel

Tags: apache-spark, jupyter-notebook

I would like to run a Jupyter notebook with a Spark kernel.

I have downloaded and installed the package spylon-kernel

```
$ pip3 install spylon-kernel
$ python -m spylon_kernel install --user
```

after I have launched a notebook it seems to have been correctly installed, until I try to execute a cell. I then obtain the following error that I do not fully understand.

```
[MetaKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/default/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 268, in dispatch_shell
    yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
  File "/home/default/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/home/default/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/home/default/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 541, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin,
  File "/home/default/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/metakernel/_metakernel.py", line 395, in do_execute
    retval = self.do_execute_direct(code)
  File "/home/default/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spylon_kernel/scala_kernel.py", line 141, in do_execute_direct
    res = self._scalamagic.eval(code.strip(), raw=False)
  File "/home/default/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spylon_kernel/scala_magic.py", line 157, in eval
    intp = self._get_scala_interpreter()
  File "/home/default/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spylon_kernel/scala_magic.py", line 46, in _get_scala_interpreter
    self._interp = get_scala_interpreter()
  File "/home/default/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spylon_kernel/scala_interpreter.py", line 568, in get_scala_interpreter
    scala_intp = initialize_scala_interpreter()
  File "/home/default/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spylon_kernel/scala_interpreter.py", line 163, in initialize_scala_interpreter
    spark_session, spark_jvm_helpers, spark_jvm_proc = init_spark()
  File "/home/default/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spylon_kernel/scala_interpreter.py", line 71, in init_spark
    conf._init_spark()
  File "/home/default/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spylon/spark/launcher.py", line 479, in _init_spark
    findspark.init(spark_home=spark_home, edit_rc=False, edit_profile=False, python_path=python_path)
  File "/home/default/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/findspark.py", line 135, in init
    py4j = glob(os.path.join(spark_python, 'lib', 'py4j-*.zip'))[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Could you please advise me on how to handle this?

Comment: have you installed spark ?